# Custom post type as page template

Tags: custom-post-types

I've been building my very first WordPress theme using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. Here are the steps I've taken so far:

1. Created custom post type via functions.php.
2. Created archive-productions.php and customised the loop.
3. Created single-productions.php and customised.

Everything is working perfectly!

I'd like to display archive-productions.php on the homepage, so i've created a page template. I've tried everything I can to get it working, but it's coming up blank.

I've spent many hours looking for a solution, but I've really hit a dead end. I always like to find my own solution, but on this occasion I need a push in the right direction. Your tips, links to tutorials or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Here's the loop I've tried on the page template:

```
<!-- Begin loop -->
<?php
   $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'productions_cpt'
      )
   );
?>

<?php $counter =0; ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php
  ++$counter;
  if($counter == 4) {
    $postclass = ' last';
    $counter = 0;
  } else { $postclass = ''; }
?>

<div class="thumb<?php echo $postclass; ?>">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
</div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no productions matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- End loop -->
```

Comment: in your wordpress root directory search n open `wp-config.php` in this file look for `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` and change it to `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` now you can see error flashing on the page instead of a blank page

Comment: can you check the code ... you are not getting the posts after defining the arguments use `get_posts()` or `wp_query` to get the posts

Comment: I feel like such a noob. I just realised I have front-page.php set up with a standard loop. This explains why I wasn't seeing anything when I set a page template for the homepage. Thank you for your help! @wordpresser debug mode is great trick.

Comment: am glad it'd help you

Comment: Thanks to @MarutiMohanty too! Checked out the codex for get_posts() and wp_query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a page template I inserted this code:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'productions', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile;
?>
```

Works like a charm. Now I just need to customise the loop so it looks pretty!